# Atom Snippets : Snippets in Local Directory

Tags: atom-editor

Hi New atom editor user here (SO AMAZING)

I have been spending an hour or so getting my snippets to work in a local folder

My snippets work when I place my snippets in the `~/.atom`

But I was wondering if I could get it to work in a local directory with following structure below :

```
example_1/
├── test.py
├── snippets
    └── snippets.cson
```

This is how my snippet look like :

```
'.source.python':
   'Console log':
     'prefix': 'log'
     'body': 'CATFORSALES'
```

I tried looking at the discussion board but still can't find any relevant. Either it is something really obvious that no one mentioned or im really blind (either way do let me know, I can get either my head checked or my eyes checked =))

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snippets are loaded from:

1. `~/.atom/snippets.cson`
2. `./snippets/*.cson` in an Atom package

So your choices for how to load snippets from a file other than #1 are to:

1. Symlink your snippets file to `~/.atom/snippets.cson`
2. Create an Atom package for your snippets

Comment: Thanks Lee, creating symlink is probably what I want to do. It would be annoying for version control and portability but creating a package for a single snippets seems like overkill